# Get value of nested form element on submit jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of an form input, which is inside a table cell, but it is getting returned as undefined.

```
$('.js-form').submit(function(event) {
        alert($(this).children().has("input[name='points']").val());
});
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<tr>
<form action='...' method='post' class='js-form'>
    <td><input type='text' name='points'/></td>
</form>
</tr>
```

There are multiple of these forms on the same page, I'm under the impression that using `$(this)` will restrict my DOM traversal to the selected form that the function is currently handling, but not sure why I don't get any value back? (there is a value in the field)

Comment: In the best case, you are trying to get the value from the `td` element. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/has/. However, your HTML is invalid and the browser might actually render a totally different DOM (e.g. move the form out of the row).

Comment: alert(("input[name='points']);

Comment: @johnSmith That line you posted will cause a syntax error, and it would just alert the literal string if it didn't. Also, there may be more than one `input[nqme='points']` which would explain why OP is seeking from the form itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
alert( $(this).find("input[name='points']").val() );
```

There is a problem with your HTML though; You can't nest a `form` between a `tr` and a `td`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5

This could mean the browser renders your code differently to what you expect. These are both acceptable structures:

```
<form action='...' method='post' class='js-form'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='points'/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action='...' method='post' class='js-form'>
                <input type='text' name='points'/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @a7omiton: You also mentioned "nested form." One `<form>` should not be nested within another; that's also invalid HTML structure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: Good observation. Have you nested a form inside a form @a7omiton ?

Comment: oh no, i don't have a nested form, when i said that i was just referring to the form inside the table

Comment: @Popnoodles in the second acceptable structure you mentioned `<tr> <td> <form> <input>`, but that stores everything in one cell?

Comment: Based on the code given, "everything" is one input field. You can't mix table structure with other elements. You need to work around that restriction.

Comment: colspan ftw :p That was the issue. Thanks so much for pointing out this flaw!